# br tags in drop down list of sql data in php

Tags: php, html, sql

So I did:

```
"<select><option>"
While($ row = mysql_get_array $ result){echo $ row['item'] . "<br>"}
"</option></select>"
```

But it doesn't recognize the `<br>` tag and just places them together. Trying to create a drop down list with my sql table data. Help please.

Btw I'm new to this so please go easy. Thanks.

Comment: Why there is a space between `$` and `row` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not how `select` tags work; the only tags appropriate within a `select` are `option` tags. You want to put each option in its own `<option>...</option>` tag, like this:

```
<select>
    <option>some option</option>
    <option>other option</option>
    <option>best option</option>
</select>
```

Replace `<br>` in your code with `</option><option>` and it will work, after you clean up some other typos:

```
<select><option>
<?php
while($row = mysql_get_array( $result ){echo $row['item'] . "</option><option>"; }
?>
</option></select>
```

Also, please [don't use `mysql_*`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php?rq=1); the `mysql_*` functions are outdated, [deprecated](https://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php), and insecure. Use [`MySQLi`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [`PDO`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.pdo.php) instead.

Comment: just did that and gave me an error. Say i want to use mysqli, how do i go about it...or pdo. I haven't used those...ever.

Comment: That's too big a topic for an answer on here, but there are lots of good tutorials (just search Google), and there are good examples at the links above. You can't just switch out `mysql_get_array` for `mysqli_get_array`, however -- you need to switch all of your database-related code.

Answer (score 0):

basic html:

```
<select name="foo">
   <option value="1">1</option>
   <option value="2">2</option>
   <option value="3">3</option>
   ...
   <option value="n">n</option>
</select>
```

`<option>` tags cannot contain arbitrary html. and a `<br>`, even if it worked, would not produce separate options.